# Can target Hover with CSS

Tags: html, css

Please can you help.

For some reason the css to target my hover will not work.

I am guessing I am using an incorrect syntax.

HTML

```
<div id="horizontalmenu"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 

<li> <a href="#">Products</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Managed Networks</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Disaster Recovery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cloud</a></li>
</ul> 
</li> 

<li> <a href="#">Why Indigo?</a></li>

<li> <a href="#">About Us</a></li>

<li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#horizontalmenu {
    margin-top: 52px;
    }

    #horizontalmenu ul {padding:1; margin:1; list-style:none; }
    #horizontalmenu li {padding-left: 20px; float:left; position:relative; display:block; border:0px solid #CC55FF; border-style:inset; } 
    #horizontalmenu li ul {display:none; position:absolute; } 
    #horizontalmenu li:hover ul{display:block; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1); height:auto; left: 0px; border: solid; border-width: 0.01em; border-color: grey;} 
    #horizontalmenu li ul li{clear:both; border-style:none;}
    #horizontalmenu li ul li:hover {background-color: #003399;}

    .horizontalmenu  a:link, a:visited{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: red;
}

    .horizontalmenu  a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
```

The text remains red, even when I hover?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `.horizontalmenu` you should write `#horizontalmenu`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class selector `.horizontalmenu` instead of an id selector `#horizontalmenu` for your last two rules but you have `<div id="horizontalmenu">` and no sign of `class=horizontalmenu` anywhere.

The `:hover` doesn't work because the rest of the selector doesn't match.

---

Of course, you make the same error for the code which changes the link red in the first place so I don't see how you get the problem you describe. Fixing both [gives the effect you are asking for](http://jsfiddle.net/4YyaB/) though.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #horizontalmenu  a:link,#horizontalmenu a:visited{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: red;
}

    #horizontalmenu  a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
```